# github say the commit missing author information, why

Tags: git, github

I committed using msysgit, and saw this weird message. But I actually have set user's name and email, why?

```
$ git last
commit 770a3f0744437a7a070f536e5a798c8d8b4e40ab
Author: Xi Hui Liang <xihuiliang@example.com>
Date:   Fri Jan 25 12:51:36 2013 +0800

    undo fix form data filter.
```

the shot

[image: the project homepage]

Comment: I just got this problem too just now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a GitHub bug to me - for instance, if you go to the page specifically for the commit, GitHub seems to load the author information just fine:

https://github.com/xihuiliang/thinkphp/commit/770a3f0744437a7a070f536e5a798c8d8b4e40ab

I'd suggest [letting them know](https://help.github.com/contact) so they can fix the bug on the main page's display.

Answer (score 2):

Your github account is not associated with the email you used. Github uses the specified e-mail to link to your account.

Go to https://github.com/settings/emails and add your kokozu.net address. Github will then properly link your commits to your github account.

Comment: But it still is a bug that it appears correctly (just name without link) in some pages and not in the one Amber mentioned...

Comment: Agreed. Linking your e-mail works around the bug and generally provides a better Github experience in my opinion, but I am not trying to claim that there isn't a bug or it shouldn't be fixed.